# I want to move my HTML player down a little

Tags: html, css

I want to move my HTML player a little bit down so that it doesn’t touch the header.

I tried changing `width` and `margin` but it didn’t work.

```html
<div class="cont overflow">
  <div class="left" style="width: 70%; margin: 30px">
    <video controls autoplay width="100%">
       <source src="http://localhost:3000/video" type="video/webm">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Your example is incomplete. It doesn't produce the same visuals as the attached screenshot, so it's not possibly to answer this without making assumptions. Please revise your minimal example.

Comment: Please put a complete example or use https://codepen.io/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I want to move my HTML player a little bit down

To move any element further down from where it would normally appear in the document flow, you can use a number of approaches:

## Approach #1: Vertical Translation

```
transform: translateY(24px);
```

The `transform: translateY()` style states how far down from normal position in the document flow you want the element to appear. ie. if you only declared `transform: translateY(0)` the element would appear in exactly the same position as it would normally appear in the document flow.

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: translateY(24px);
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: translateY(72px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

## Approach #2: Relative Positioning

```
position: relative;
top: 24px;
```

The `top` style states how far down from normal position in the document flow you want the element to appear. ie. if you only declared `top: 0` the element would appear in exactly the same position as it would normally appear in the document flow.

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  position: relative;
  top: 24px;
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
  position: relative;
  top: 72px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Why is this being down-voted?  It's a well-thought out answer with much more detail than the original question.

Comment: Thank you, @J.Murray. I find the phenomenon of widespread anonymous downvotes across StackOverflow just defies explanation sometimes.

Comment: Thank you for your continuing efforts and hard-work.  I agree on the current climate on SO. Rather hoping its a patch of bad weather that clears up before too long.

Answer (score -3):

It's simple, in the HTML use so many `<br>` as you need so it don't touch. **Try it**